# The parameter is incorrect when creating a symmetric key

Tags: c#, forms, tcp, cryptography, diffie-hellman

I am doing a TCP server and client application. I need to encrypt and decrypt messages, however before that I need to create a symmetric key that works with AES algorithm. I used Diffie-Hellman public key exchange between server and client. However, when I use the public key as a parameter, I get an error that the parameter is incorrect.

I use Receive and Send to transfer data between server and client.

```cs
static byte[] Receive(NetworkStream netStream)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] receive = new byte[STD_MSG_SIZE];
        int length = netStream.Read(receive, 0, receive.Length);
        string x = Convert.ToBase64String(receive, 0, length);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x);
    }
    catch (Exception except)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error at receive\n" + except.Message + "\n" + except.StackTrace);
        return null;
    }
}

static void Send(NetworkStream netStream, byte[] message)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] send = message;
        netStream.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
    }
    catch (Exception except)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error at send\n" + except.Message + "\n" + except.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

This is the code in Client, where I generate the public key, send it to the server and then I receive public key from server.

```cs
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(STD_IP), STD_PORT);

ECDiffieHellmanCng alice = new ECDiffieHellmanCng();
alice.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
alice.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
byte[] publicKey = alice.PublicKey.ToByteArray();

NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

Send(ns, publicKey);

byte[] data = Receive(ns);

textBox1.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(data);

byte[] simKey = alice.DeriveKeyMaterial(ECDiffieHellmanCngPublicKey.FromByteArray(data, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob));
```

This is the code in Server. I use textbox in forms, to show the public key.

```cs
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(STD_IP), STD_PORT);
tcpListener.Start();

ECDiffieHellmanCng bob = new ECDiffieHellmanCng();
bob.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
bob.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
byte[] publicKey = bob.PublicKey.ToByteArray();

TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

byte[] data = Receive(ns);

textBox1.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(data);

Send(ns, publicKey);

byte[] simKey = bob.DeriveKeyMaterial(ECDiffieHellmanCngPublicKey.FromByteArray(data, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob));
```

I got these values from data in client and server when I commented simKey.

**Client textbox**: UlVOTE5VSUFBQUFBdXZXTXgzdHFUb0hZVGY0NnFyNlovVWJuRCtUMlZqMTVGZEN5RmIrYnFLRHN3WTZ5clJIemlNblAzYUJDZUpaaW5oVTN6ODFVUWZZaWNiRUNSaUR4NFNJQXBFdE5uYzl0Z1VOV01qNTllSVRaRCtOdGp2V3lIMzZWR21FdDBUSzFKUEx1UTBFZ2tXTXRFU0E1dTJWSkxoWk1FU2NKQ2tXMUhkc0hGWUQwUmFldHJ3RT0=

**Server textbox**:
UlVOTE5VSUFBQUFCcWQ3TnZzK0pFQ3BydFFYK2k4T1ErN3pGNXZQSzh6S1I3UEJvUzN3VERkdFB0N05nM2tNWi9TTXkzVFRpZ0JBMmhQdlJJakhObWJ1WlZhc3ZFUTZMUnkwQVdockhMcjh6SzlSTUtsbloxWnVwcDFqMGh3cTNNK04yNXlraUNrMk51b1BVSlZVQkJXOFM4TWQ2eEp6NzQvbHNHSWY1Sy9MUUxnZEp3OUhad2pNcW85dz0=

Comment: What's the exception (with at least the portion of the stack trace including whatever framework method you called)?

Answer (score 0):

The use of the `Read` method, to my surprise, is correct as long as the buffer is large enough to hold the public key.

The problem is that you then base64 encode the result within the `Receive` method, which is supposed to return just bytes. Besides messing up your design - it is definitely not *least surprise* if a method to read data also encodes it - this will also make the parsing of the public key fail.

It's OK to base 64 encode for your text box. But as long as you don't need binary encoding you should leave it out. Or at least decode it before use.